# Segmented Control and tableViews

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am trying to change the text of a UITableView Cell when i change my segmented control. I am using a custom segmented control but thats not important. In the code below i am saying when the second segment is selected, change the text to Heyyy and I cant figure out how pass in the cell object.

```
- (void)segmentedControlChangedValue:(HMSegmentedControl *)segmentedControl {
if(segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1){
     _cell.textLabel.text = @"Heyyy";
    [self tableView:_cell cellForRowAtIndexPath:];
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than trying to change the cell **view** when the segmented control changes, try changing the *data* that the cell reads from and then updating that cell.

You could add a variable called `NSString *myCellText`.

```
@implementation ViewController {
    NSString *myCellText;
}
```

When the segmented control changes, you could do this:

```
- (void)segmentedControlChangedValue:(HMSegmentedControl *)segmentedControl {
    if(segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1){
         myCellText = @"Heyyy";
    }

    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPathOfCell] 
                withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
```

Then in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` you can check for that specific index path and set the cell's text `myCellText`.

Comment: thanks ur missing a colon tho :) reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:

Comment: Thanks, this is a prime example of where I should run code in Xcode before posting on Stack.

Comment: I clarified where the variable could be declared so a setter is not necessary.

Comment: also its saying No visible @interface for 'MyMusicViewController' declares the selector 'reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:'

Comment: does `MyMusicViewController` implement `UITableViewDataSource`?

Comment: when you say self.myTableView, do i have to create the myTableView Object or? and for indexPathOfCell what do i say for that. I am looking to refresh the whole tabelView

Comment: replace `self.myTableView` with whatever table view has the cell you want to update

Comment: if you want to refresh the entire table view you can call `[self.myTableView reloadData];`